# Using HTML buttons and textbox in asp.net website

Tags: html, asp.net, html-input

I got an offer to create a website and I want to use c# to do that, which means I must use asp.net framework right?
I want to use my HTML textboxes and buttons to insert into my datebase instead of asp.net button and text boxes, I created two text boxes using HTML form and input tag, gave them a name and ID each, set runat attribute to server, then I tried to access my HTML text boxes in the button onclick method, but I can't even see the names of the textboxes in the list of objects in my C# code. So I can't make reference to them, to perform any codes using them.

I've tried:

```
<form>
    <input name="username" id="username" type="text" runat="server" />

    <input name="pword" id="pword" type="password" runat="server" />

    <asp:button Name="login" Text="Login" runat="server" />
<form/>
```

When I tried accessing it in the .cs page I couldn't see username and pword.

Comment: Hi. If you're trying to get started with C# and .NET I would highly recommend looking at some free content on .NET 5 and .NET 6 for new development.  ASP.NET (with aspx pages) has been around for a long time, and while it still works, is not recommended for new development.  Try starting with this video on Razor Pages by IAmTimCorey https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68towqYcQlY

Comment: No I'm not getting started with C#, I already know the C# basics sir...but I'm not really familiar with Asp.net I'm still learning sir...but I'll ckeck thank you.

Comment: the whole point and suggestnig and issue here? If you going to adopt asp.net, then it would make no sense to now not to adopt asp.net controls. Failure to do this means you quite much have to toss out "most" of the asp.net features. So, you can use HTML controls in a asp.net web page, but for the most part, using asp.net controls means that you get automatic wiring up of events for your code behind written in c#. So, the old saying when in Rome do as they do? Same applies to asp.net. You as much as possible want to use asp.net controls, else little reason exists to use asp.net.

Comment: The point of me choosing Asp.net is i know more about C# programming language and im using it to develop a software so i know most of the alogrithms and thier functions, but im also into creating of websites and i want to use C# for my serverside programming or backend processing...i was told i could only do that through asp.net or is there any other way i can use C# and SQL for my backend processing for my Html site?